# External Hard Drive does not load on boot

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive

My external harddrive works fine except for one thing, if I put my computer to sleep or restart it, the hard drive will not load automatically and I have to unplug it, and plug it back it, for it to function.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but whenever I search for one in google results are swamped with people who have hard drives which do not boot at all.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate, though I recall having the issue on XP as well, prior to formatting.

Comment: This sounds like the HDD is one of those "green" drives.  Sadly there isn't a great deal you can about this behavior if thats the case.  Specific product information might help.

Comment: Could be incompatible hardware. Do you have any other USB ports that you can try plugging the HDD into?